# android.arch.persistence.room:testing depends on Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Long time ago, I've enabled Kotlin support for my android studio project, then removed it. Android Studio, hovewer, doesn't stop to notify me about newer kotlin libs version available. Whatever.

I've switched off Kotling plugin, removed it and any Kotling configs in gradle(and, if it means something, all .kt files were removed too)

I've got my project written on Java, without any Kotlin libs\plugins enbabled\etc.
I'm writing some Room migration tests and trying to launch them, but got message that

```
Conflict with dependency 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib' in project ':my-project'. Resolved versions for app (1.1.2-3) and test app (1.2.41) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.
```

Going through dependency tree and testing in new project, I've realised, that kotlin-stdlib dependency is added when I use

```
androidTestImplementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.1.1'
```

I found that **android.arch.persistence.room.migration** adds kotlin-stdlid dependency.
I have decompiled that jar and found no reason to include kotlin library.

I'm still living with all of that Kotlin stuff just because I need to make my tests working.

I have several questions about this:

1) Can I use '**android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.1.1**' without kotlin dependencies?

2) If 1 question answer is 'No', can I use kotlin dependency only for testing?

3) How can I get rid of old kotlin lib (1.1.2-3) in my project. There is no kotlin lib defined in gradle files or anywhere else in the project.

**UPD: kotlin-stlib output for androidDependencies:**

```
:my-project:androidDependencies
debug
debugCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3@jar

debugRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3@jar

debugAndroidTest
debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.41@jar

debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.41@jar

debugUnitTest
debugUnitTestCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3@jar

debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3@jar

release
releaseCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3@jar

releaseRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3@jar

releaseUnitTest
releaseUnitTestCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3@jar

releaseUnitTestRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.2-3@jar
```

Comment: "I found that android.arch.persistence.room.migration adds kotlin-stdlid dependency" -- yes, I can see that in its POM file. That has been there since `1.0.0`, so my guess is that this is not a bug. You could try to `exclude` the `kotlin-stdlib` transitive dependency in your `build.gradle` file and see if it works.

Comment: @CommonsWare you're right, it's not a bug. But excluding this dependency will lead to test not working with another error: Unable to load class 'kotlin.reflect.KDeclarationContainer'.

Comment: Well, that sucks. I guess it is required then, at least for testing. In terms of #3, you may be pulling in `kotlin-stdlib` via transitive dependencies from an `implementation` or `api` artifact, in addition to the one that you are getting from `androidTestImplementation`. Run a Gradle dependency report to try to determine where it is coming from.

Comment: @CommonsWare added dependency tree output about kotlin-stdlib - still can't understand where this lib involved. For now I'm using force override of this dependency using resolutionStrategy { force 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlinstdlib:1.2.41' }

Comment: @CommonsWare Found what dependency in my project requires kotlin-stlib 1.1.2-3 using gralew dependencies command(it's a lot better than androidDependencies command, because it's showing real tree instead of some sort of flat list of dependencies) Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my questions:

*1) Can I use '**android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.1.1**' without kotlin dependencies?*

**No**, because it relies on it. I found usage of **kotlin.reflect.KDeclarationContainer** class, for example.

*2) If 1 question answer is 'No', can I use kotlin dependency only for testing?*

**Yes**, this lib will be available only for testing using

```
androidTestImplementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:testing:x.x.x'
```

*3) How can I get rid of old kotlin lib (1.1.2-3) in my project. There is no kotlin lib defined in gradle files or anywhere else in the project.*

In my case, this lib was a dependency to another dependency in project.

You can simply detect all transitive dependecies using

**./gradlew dependencies**

command or via Android Studio GUI using

**Gradle --> :your-module --> Tasks --> help --> dependencies**

I've just updated this third party lib to latest version so dependent kotlin-stlib versions became equal.

If you want to force override kotlin version to use, you can do it in your module's  **build.gradle**:

```
// This is example to force using 1.2.41 kotlin version instead of any other **FOR ALL** libraries
   configurations.all {
      resolutionStrategy {
          force 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.41'
      }
}
```

Also, you can be more precise and exclude or force transitive dependency for particular module dependency. Please look at:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html